# Datasets for software defined network (SDN)

Tags: dataset

I am working on a project with Software Defined Networks (SDN), and new to SDN area. I was checking around internet to find a benchmark dataset, which is a flow based dataset inorder to apply ML techniques. I havenot found one yet. SDN is  a TCP/IP based network. But SDN offers a way to collect the statistics from dataplane devices. I am searching whether there is a flow based statistics benchmark dataset that is publically available for SDN research. I can find the packetcaptures over traditional networks, but I am looking for flow based datasets collected over SDN.

The other option is to simulate a network and inject traffic with tools, but the datasets created like this has less traffic diversity. Another option is to create flows from the existing packet captures, but this needs  packet parser.